# Drawing complex diagrams with TikZ using gradients

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, asymptote

I am relatively new to LaTeX. I don't find it an issue writing documents and so on but when I try to draw diagrams I run into some bother. I was reading an article and found this diagram:

[image: picture]

I was also reading about TikZ an have started drawing some diagrams, but nowhere as good as this. So, I was wondering, is it possible to draw something like this, without all the writing with TikZ, i.e., reproduce this as a plain diagram? Or is this beyond the capabilities of TikZ?

Comment: I would say that this kind of graphic is definitely not beyond the scope of `tikZ` as it is quite schematic. The question is if it is worth the work to build *one* such graphic in `tikZ`. That will definitely depend on your `tikZ` skills. If you had a whole bunch of quite similar graphics where you could reuse some of the code or build even templates for several features the effort would easier pay off.

Comment: Text, arrows, lines and chemical formulas is all made easy by LaTeX and TikZ. I believe, that the hard part will be the complex shadings and the textures. Maybe this can be helpfull!?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103980/tikz-define-pattern-with-reference-to-external-picture

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image]

Basic elements of this kind of diagrams with `Asymptote`, MWE:

```
% cycle.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
import graph;
import roundedpath;
import math;

//texpreamble("\usepackage{upgreek}");
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
real sc=2;
unitsize(sc*1bp);

// 1. bounding ellipse
guide ell=(150,60)..(75,120)..(3.4,60)..(75,0)..cycle;

// 2. day
pen penA=rgb(0.773,0.831,0.882);
pen penB=rgb(0.09,0.09,0.09);

pair a=(70,60);
pair b=(100,60);

fill(box((0,0),(90,120)),penA);
axialshade(box((0,0),(100,120)),penA,a, extenda=false,penB,b, extendb=false);

// night

fill(box((100,0),(150,120)),black);

// sun
pair sunPos=(51,107);
real sunR=3;
pen sunClr=rgb(0.98,0.973,0.149);
pen BorderPen=rgb(0.145,0.361,0.435)+1bp;

// sun beam
guide sunBeam=(2.5,0)--(Cos(360/16),Sin(360/16))--(Cos(360/16),-Sin(360/16))--cycle;

for(int i=0;i<8;++i){
  filldraw(shift(sunPos)*rotate(360/8*i)*scale(sunR)*sunBeam,sunClr,BorderPen);
}

filldraw(shift(sunPos)*scale(sunR)*unitcircle,sunClr,BorderPen);

// water
real wave0=83;
real waveAm=1.5;
real waveT=16;

real f(real x){return wave0+waveAm*sin(2pi/waveT*(x-5)); };
pen waveLinePen=rgb(0.329,0.533,0.675)+1.5bp;
pen waterClr=rgb(0.392,0.588,0.725)+opacity(0.382);

guide water=(150,0)--reverse(graph(f,0,150))--(0,0)--cycle;
filldraw(water,waterClr,waveLinePen);

//=== moon
pen moonLight=rgb(1,1,0.965);

pair[] moonCP={
(104,100),
(116,102),
(119,108),
(106,111),
(112,107),
(112,105),
};

guide moon=moonCP[0]..controls moonCP[1] and moonCP[2] .. moonCP[3]
.. controls moonCP[4] and moonCP[5]..cycle;

filldraw(moon,moonLight,BorderPen);

// bottom

fill(box((10,0),(150,30)),white+opacity(0.3));


// thin film
pen thinFilmPenA=rgb(0.325,0.459,0.416);
pen thinFilmPenB=rgb(0.357,0.514,0.478);

pair[] thinFilmCP={
(9,30),
(16,28),
(20,27),
(25,27),
(34,25),
(48,25),
(60,24),
(68,24),
(89,24),
(109,25),
(122,25),
(135,25),
(138,25),
(141,28),
(143,30),
(139,31),
(134,31),
(131,31),
(129,31),
(131,35),
(130,39),
(126,40),
(122,41),
(118,43),
(114,44),
(111,44),
(108,43),
(105,42),
(103,39),
(101,37),
(98,35),
(96,33),
(93,32),
(83,32),
(75,31),
(67,31),
(63,31),
(60,32),
(57,36),
(54,38),
(51,40),
(47,41),
(44,42),
(40,43),
(36,42),
(34,41),
(31,39),
(29,36),
(26,33),
(24,33),
(22,33),
(16,32),
(13,31),
};

guide thinFilm=graph(thinFilmCP,operator..)..cycle;

filldraw(thinFilm,thinFilmPenB,thinFilmPenA);

// === biofilm
pen bioFilmPenA=rgb(0.325,0.459,0.416);
pen bioFilmPenB=rgb(0.455,0.51,0.404);

pair[] bioFilmCP={
(16,28),
(20,27),
(25,27),
(34,25),
(48,25),
(60,24),
(68,24),
(89,24),
(109,25),
(122,25),
(135,25),
(138,25),
(141,28),
(143,30),
(138,30),
(130,31),
(123,31),
(114,33),
(103,32),
(99,31),
(93,31),
(86,30),
(76,30),
(68,30),
(60,30),
(57,30),
(52,31),
(43,32),
(33,32),
(28,31),
(24,31),
(19,30),
(16,31),
(11,30),
};

guide bioFilm=graph(bioFilmCP,operator..)..cycle;

filldraw(bioFilm,bioFilmPenB,bioFilmPenA);

//=== left stone
pen StonePenA=rgb(0.149,0.145,0.063);
pen StonePenB=rgb(0.302,0.259,0.141);

pair[] leftStoneCP={
(27,30),
(30,29),
(34,29),
(38,29),
(41,29),
(46,29),
(50,29),
(54,30),
(56,31),
(56,33),
(56,36),
(55,38),
(52,39),
(49,40),
(46,40),
(42,41),
(38,41),
(34,41),
(31,39),
(29,36),
(27,33),
};

guide leftStone=graph(leftStoneCP,operator..)..cycle;

filldraw(leftStone,StonePenB,StonePenA);

//== right Stone
pair[] rightStoneCP={
(100,32),
(102,31),
(105,31),
(108,31),
(111,31),
(115,31),
(119,31),
(122,31),
(125,32),
(127,32),
(130,33),
(130,35),
(129,38),
(126,39),
(125,40),
(122,41),
(120,41),
(118,43),
(114,43),
(111,43),
(107,42),
(105,41),
(104,39),
(102,37),
(101,35),
};

guide rightStone=graph(rightStoneCP,operator..)..cycle;

filldraw(rightStone,StonePenB,StonePenA);


// ====
clip(ell);

draw(ell,blue+2bp);


string[] sLabel={
"P>R",
"R>P",
"CO_2",
"O_2",
"Zn^{2+}",
"H_2AsO_4^{-}",
"NO_3^{-}\rightarrow N_2",
"MnO_x^{-}\rightarrow Mn^{2+}",
"FeO_x^{-}\rightarrow Fe^{2+}",
"CO_2",
"O_2",
"Zn^{2+}",
"H_2AsO_4^{-}",
"NH_4^{+}\rightarrow NO_3^{-}",
"Mn^{2+}\rightarrow MnO_x",
"Fe^{2+}\rightarrow FeO_x",
"Fe^{3+}\rightarrow Fe^{2+}",
"DOC\rightarrow DIC",
"\mathit{biofilm}",
};

pair[] labelPos={
(42,35),
(115,37),
(90,64),
(140,64),
(104,59),
(122,58),
(113,24),
(106,17),
(99,11),
(12,64),
(72,64),
(25,56),
(62,49),
(42,21),
(51,15),
(61,9),
(37,77),
(36,72),
(74,27),

};

pen[] labelClr={
white,
white,
white,
white,
white,
white,
white,
white,
white,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,
black,

};

for(int i=0;i<sLabel.length;++i){
  label("$\mathsf{"+sLabel[i]+"}$",labelPos[i],labelClr[i]);
}


string[] xLabel={
"h\upnu\uparrow\uparrow",
"T_{air}\uparrow",
"ET\uparrow",

"pH\uparrow",
"T_{water}\uparrow",
"DO,Eh\uparrow",
"streamflow\uparrow\!or\!\downarrow",

"pH\downarrow",
"T_{water}\downarrow",
"DO,Eh\downarrow",
"streamflow\downarrow\!or\!\uparrow",

"h\upnu\downarrow\downarrow",
"T_{air}\downarrow",
"ET\downarrow",


};

pair[] xlabelPos={
(7,112),(7,107),(7,102),
(-3,23),
(-3,18),
(-3,13),
(-3,8),

(155,23),
(155,18),
(155,13),
(155,8),

(135,112),
(135,107),
(135,102),

};

pair[] xlabelOff={
E,E,E,
E,E,E,E,
W,W,W,W,
E,E,E,
};


for(int i=0;i<xLabel.length;++i){
  label("$\mathsf{"+xLabel[i]+"}$",xlabelPos[i],xlabelOff[i],black);
}

// springArrow
pair[] springArrowCP={
(48,102),
(44,100),
(47,99),
(42,97),
(45,95),
(41,92),
(44,90),
(40,88),
(42,85),
(38,80),
};

guide springArrow=roundedpath(graph(springArrowCP,operator--),1);
draw(springArrow,black+0.8bp,Arrow(HookHead,size=3));

// thin arrows left

guide[] thinArrowB={
(72,70)..(67,86)..(56,94),
(23,94)..(13,84)..(10,69),
(49,37)..(56,39)..(61,45),
(26,52)..(28,44)..(34,39), // Zn->

};

for(int i=0;i<thinArrowB.length;++i){
  draw(thinArrowB[i],black+0.8bp,Arrow(HookHead,size=3));
}


guide[] thinArrowW={
(90,68)..(95,82)..(107,91)  ,
(119,91)..(132,85)..(141,69),
(124,57)..(122,49)..(116,44),
(112,44)..(107,49)..(105,56),
};

for(int i=0;i<thinArrowW.length;++i){
  draw(thinArrowW[i],white+0.8bp,Arrow(HookHead,size=3));
}

struct hydra{
  guide stem,left,right;
  pen p;
  void operator init(guide stem, guide left,guide right,pen p=currentpen){
    this.stem=stem;
    this.left=left;
    this.right=right;        
    this.p=p;
  }
};

void draw(hydra h){
  draw(h.stem, h.p+3bp);
  draw(h.left, h.p+3bp,Arrow(HookHead,size=10,filltype=Fill));
  draw(h.right,h.p+3bp,Arrow(HookHead,size=10,filltype=Fill));
}

hydra hydraRW=hydra(
(142,57)..(140,51)..(137,47)
,(137,47)..(135,39)..(135,29)
,(137,47)..(131,44)..(124,42)
,white
);

guide gtmp=(10,54)..(18,43)..(30,38);
hydra hydraRB=hydra(
subpath(gtmp,0,1)
,subpath(gtmp,1,2)
,(18,43)..(22,35)..(21,28)
,black
);

draw(hydraRW);
draw(hydraRB);

// plant

pair[] plantCP={
(0,0),
(1,1),
(2,2),
(3,3),
(3,4),
(4,6),
(7,6),
(9,5),
(11,7),
(12,9),
(12,11),
(13,14),
(14,16),
(15,17),
(13,16),
(12,15),
(10,13),
(10,11),
(9,9),
(8,7),
(6,8),
(4,8),
(3,7),
(2,6),
};

guide plant=roundedpath(graph(plantCP),0.5)..cycle;
pen plantPenA=rgb(0.133,0.141,0.067)+1bp;
pen plantPenB=rgb(0.294,0.38,0.169)+opacity(0.7);

pair[] plantPos={
(128,33),
(121,41),
(91,32),
(85,32),
(65,31),
(38,39),
(34,43),
(14,31),
};
for(int i=0;i<plantPos.length;++i){
  filldraw(shift(plantPos[i])*plant,plantPenB,plantPenA);
}
\end{asy}
\caption{Drawing complex diagrams with \texttt{Asymptote} using gradients}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
% 
% To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:
% 
%     sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
%     add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
% 
% and run `latexmk -pdf cycle.tex`.
```

Comment: This is great, but does asymptote not require python to run? Is there a method for converting this to latex code? I know it can be done with something like inkscape.

Comment: @user36060: No, `Asymptote` does not require `python` to run, it has its own power syntax itself. And this `MWE`, `cycle.tex`, is already a valid `LaTeX` code, as you can see.
It can be processed in three steps: `pdflatex cycle.tex`, `asy -f pdf cycle-1.asy` `pdflatex cycle.tex`.
`Python` is needed to run the `latexmk` script, but this is just
for mere convenience.

Comment: I don't understand your three step guide above, this looks like linux? I'm on windows...

Comment: @user36060: Commands `pdflatex` and `asy` are part of `TeX Live` distribution and they are platform-independent.

Comment: By copying this exact example into latex I receive the following error: File asymptote.sty not found. \usepackage.

Comment: Amazing! Wait a second... Did you "draw" it by coding manually, or did you use a drawing tool like inkscape or so.

Comment: @schmendrich: Actually, I used a coordinate grid on top of the original image
as is outlined in [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz/129801#129801)
to digitize contours of the objects in a scene.

Comment: Why can't I upvote twice? This is awesome and looks almost better than the original but the font is to narrow so the edges of the graphics elements do hinder reading the text a bit. I'ds suggest to use a bolder font. Again, awesome!

Comment: @math: Well, thanks, I like it too, as well as the original. It's just a `MWE`, the font of labels can be changed to any available `LaTeX` font specification, the simplest 
would be to change all `\mathsf` to `\mathbf` in `labels`, 
otherwise check the questions on this site about bolder fonts.

Answer (score 10):

As the OP said "without text" and as "a plain diagram", I've left out all the text and the arrows. I'm not at all happy with the reeds/eels, they look a bit rubbish. The main idea was to add a kind of 'texture' to some of the elements.

The first requirement for the textures is this bitmap:

[image]

which I just generated using Inkscape. This should be saved as `sand.png`

The rest looks like this:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\definecolor{wave}{HTML}{54888C}

\definecolor{sea day}{HTML}{80A0C0}
\definecolor{sea night}{HTML}{314D6D}

\definecolor{sky day}{HTML}{DDE4EA}
\definecolor{sky night}{HTML}{000000}

\definecolor{biofilm day}{HTML}{818A70}
\definecolor{biofilm night}{HTML}{4F583E}

\definecolor{biofilm top day}{HTML}{6A8279}
\definecolor{biofilm top night}{HTML}{48625F}

\definecolor{seabed day}{HTML}{B4B4BB}
\definecolor{seabed night}{HTML}{494949}

\definecolor{rock}{HTML}{44401F}
\definecolor{reed}{HTML}{4F5F2A}

\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[day,night]{day to night}{100bp}{%
    color(0bp)=(day); color(50bp)=(day); color(60bp)=(night); color(100bp)=(night)%
}%

\tikzset{
    day to night shading/.code={
        \colorlet{day}{#1 day}%
        \colorlet{night}{#1 night}%
        \tikzset{shading=day to night}%
    },
    make sandy/.style={
        postaction={
            clip,
            postaction={
                path picture={
                    % Very crude tiling method. Am sure there is an easier way.
                    \path  let \p1=(path picture bounding box.south west),
                    \p2=(path picture bounding box.north east) in 
                    [shift={(path picture bounding box.south west)},x=#1,y=#1]
                    \pgfextra
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nx{ceil(\x2-\x1)/#1}
                        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ny{ceil(\y2-\y1)/#1}
                        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\size{#1}
                    \endpgfextra
                    \foreach \x in {0,...,\nx}{
                        \foreach \y in {0,...,\ny}{
                            (\x,\y) 
                            node [inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west, opacity=0.125]{%
                                \pgfimage[interpolate=true, width=\size,height=\size]{sand.png}
                            }
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    },
    make sandy/.default=32,
    sky/.style={
        day to night shading=sky,
    },
    sea/.style={
        day to night shading=sea,
        decoration={snake, segment length=1cm, amplitude=0.125cm},
        postaction={draw=wave, ultra thick}
    },
    sea bed/.style={
        day to night shading=seabed,
        make sandy=32
    },
    biofilm decoration/.style={
        decoration={random steps, segment length=0.25cm, amplitude=0.0625cm, raise=0.125cm}, 
    },
    biofilm top/.style={
        day to night shading=biofilm top, 
        biofilm decoration,
        decorate,
        rounded corners=0.125cm,
    },
    biofilm/.style={
        day to night shading=biofilm, 
        rounded corners=0.125cm,
        biofilm decoration,
        make sandy=64
    },
    rock/.style={
        draw=rock!75!black,
        very thick, 
        fill=rock,   
        rounded corners=0.25cm,
        make sandy=128
    },
    reed/.style={
        rounded corners=0.0625cm,
        draw=reed!75!black,
        thick,
        fill=reed,
        insert path={
            { ([shift={#1}]0,0) [x=0.75cm,y=0.75cm]  --
            ++(0.375,0.75) -- ++(0.375,-0.0625) -- ++(0.225,0.75) -- 
            ++(0.25,0.25) -- ++(-0.125,-0.25) -- ++(-0.25,-0.875) --
            ++(-0.375,0.0625) -- ++(-0.375,-0.75) -- cycle
            }
        }
    },
    moon/.style={
        fill=white,
        draw=sea night,
        very thick
    },
    sun/.style={
        fill=yellow,
        draw=sea night,
        very thick
    }
}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round]

\begin{scope}

\clip ellipse [x radius=5, y radius=4];

\path [sky] (-5,0)  rectangle (5,4); 

\path [sea] 
    (-5,-2) -- (-5,1.5) decorate  { -- (5,1.5) } -- (5,-2) -- cycle;

\path [sea bed] 
    (-5,-4)  rectangle (5,-1.75);

\path [biofilm top, yshift=-1.75cm]
    (-10,0) -- (-3.5,0) -- 
    ++(0.5,0.75) -- ++(0.75,0) -- ++(0.75,-0.5) -- ++(0.75,-0.25) --  
    (1.375,0) -- 
    ++(0.5,0.75) -- ++(0.75,0) -- ++(0.75,-0.5) -- ++(0.75,-0.25) --  
    (10,0) |- (-10,-0.25) -- cycle;

\path [biofilm]
    (-5,-1.75) -- (-5,-2.5) decorate  { -- (5,-2.5) } -- (5,-1.75) -- cycle;

\path [rock, yshift=-1.75cm]
      (-3.375,0) -- ++(0.375,0.75) -- ++(0.625,0) -- ++(0.75,-0.375) --
    ++(0.25,-0.5) -- ++(-0.5,-0.0)  --  ++(-0.375,-0.125) -- cycle
      (1.5,0) -- ++(0.375,0.75) -- ++(0.625,0) -- ++(0.75,-0.375) --
    ++(0.25,-0.5) -- ++(-0.5,-0.0)  --  ++(-0.375,-0.125) -- cycle;

% Reeds or eels?
\foreach \p in {(-4.25,0), (-3,0.75), (-2.75,0.5), (-1,0), (0.5,0.125), (1,0.125), (3,0.5), (3.5,0.125)}
    \path [shift={(0,-1.75)}, reed={\p}];

\path [moon] (2,3.5) arc (90:-90:0.25 and 0.375) arc (-90:90:0.5 and 0.375);

\path [sun, shift={(-2,3)}] ++(-22.5:0.25) 
    \foreach \a [evaluate={\r=mod(\a,2)/4+0.25;}]in {0,...,15}{ -- (\a*22.5-22.5:\r)} -- cycle;
\path [sun] (-2,3) circle [radius=0.25];

\end{scope}

\draw [ultra thick, draw=sea night!75!black] ellipse [x radius=5, y radius=4];

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, there maybe issues with some viewers or image converters on Linux which depend on old or oldish versions of poppler. Sometimes the textures will not be shown.

Comment: My answer to [TikZ: Define pattern with reference to external picture](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103980) might make the image pattern easier. The [first revision](http://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/107144/1) actually used the same approach.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The easiest to use that image as a mask.

Comment: Dimension too large (10,0) |- (-10,-0.25) -- cycle;

Comment: @user36060 no errors on 200 successive compilations. It may depend on the seed which can be set manually.

Answer (score 7):

Just as a start, this answer tries to provide the very basic concepts to accomplish this kind of drawings, thus it's far from being *good*.

First, the gradient. TikZ provides the `fadings` library which is of help in this case. Indeed, one may notice that it is possible to decouple into two parts the gradient: an constant one in the `night` part and a second one in the `day` part in which the gradient is uniform. For this reason I would define two fadings:

```
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade left]
  \shade[left color=transparent!100,
         right color=transparent!75] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);      
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=uniform fade]
  \shade[left color=transparent!65,
         right color=transparent!65] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);      
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
```

to be applied to the ellipse as:

```
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4cm,y radius=3cm]; % draw the ellipse
\clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4cm,y radius=3cm]; % cut everything else

% using rectangles for simplicity: the fading is applied here
\fill [path fading=fade left,black] (1.5,-3) rectangle (-3,3);
\fill [path fading=uniform fade,black] (1.5,-3) rectangle (4,3);
```

For simplicity I used rectangles: if one *really* needs to draw this, it worth to find the right shape (a sort of ellipse cut) to avoid the `\clip` part.

Second: putting the backgrounds. There are several `backgrounds` so that library is absolutely needed.

So, my start would be:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
  decorations.pathmorphing,
  fadings,
  patterns,
  positioning,
  shapes.geometric}

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=fade left]
  \shade[left color=transparent!100,
         right color=transparent!75] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);      
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=uniform fade]
  \shade[left color=transparent!65,
         right color=transparent!65] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);      
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4cm,y radius=3cm];
\clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4cm,y radius=3cm];

\fill [path fading=fade left,black] (1.5,-3) rectangle (-4,3);
\fill [path fading=uniform fade,black] (1.5,-3) rectangle (4,3);

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% have to clip again
\clip (0,0) ellipse [x radius=4cm,y radius=3cm];

\fill (1.5,0)rectangle(4,3);
\node[semicircle,very thick,blue!60!cyan!80!gray,draw,fill=white,rotate=-94] at (2,2){}; 


\fill[blue!60!cyan!80!gray,decorate,decoration={snake,segment length=7mm}](4.5,0.5)--(-4.5,0.5)--(-4.7,-1.25)--(4.7,-1.25);

\fill[green!40!gray](4.5,-0.5)--(-4.5,-0.5)(-4,-1)arc(242:298:8.5cm);

\fill[gray,
opacity=0.2](-4,-1)arc(242:298:8.5cm)--++(0,-2)-|(-4,-1); 
\end{scope}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The layer foreground is not yet used, but should be necessary later on.

Comment: There's a glitch on the left of the picture: the cause is the bad filling I did.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting. Don't be shy and try at least to provide an explanation for this: admittedly the result is not as good as the one of Mark, but intentionally this answer was explicitly given as "starting point". Look the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, you might consider an alternative - draw it in Inkscape:

- The image can be [exported in a way](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) that [facilitates embedding in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125324/including-pdf-tex-images-from-inkscape)
- You can leverage LaTeX notation to include math in the image and ensure your fonts are nice

This hybrid approach enables you to use the strengths of Inkscape *and* LaTeX, and it will probably take less time than it takes to implement this with TikZ.