# create pdf figures from pdf_tex and pdf files

Tags: graphics, pdf

I am writing an academic article and I saved all my figures in svg format. Then I converted (after a few cosmetic stuffs) it to pdf_tex/pdf so that they fit the paper . The problem is that my editor asks me the figures in pdf format. How can I convert all my pdf_tex/pdf files in selftcontained pdf figures so that the rendering when including the generated pdf will be the same ?

Comment: What exactly is `pdf_tex/pdf` files?

Comment: Does this question help you? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125324

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \input{Colors.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

To address the problem with objects outside the pdf, you could define the size of the resulting pdf. But I am afraid, the numbers have to be adjusted for each figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \parbox[c][30cm][c]{30cm}{
        \hspace*{1cm}
        \input{Colors.pdf_tex}
    }

\end{document}
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

In fact `standalone` itself is capable of adding desired margins. This can be done with

> border={left right bottom top}

```
\documentclass[border={1cm 1cm 1cm 1cm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

    \input{Colors.pdf_tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This work very well expect that I have some text outside the region defined by the pdf file (Colors.pdf) and the document seems to be bounded by the size of the pdf image. Any idea ? Thanks in davance