# pdf_tex problem

Tags: pdf, svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape to create `.pdf_tex` graphics. While drawing my figure on Inkscape, I import an `.png` image, than I save my drawing as PDF and call it in my LaTeX code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \input{C:/latex/dessins-svg-inscape/dessin2.pdf_tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

However, I don't find the image I imported on Inkscape; I don't find the drawings I made (I drew circles), I find only mathematical formulas that I added.

Please could you help me solve this problem.

Comment: There is already an [answered question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125324/25077) with almost the same aim: If you agree that it is in fact the same: please remove your question. Else you might want to clarify what is the difference.