# Replacing eps to pdf_tex

Tags: pdftex, inkscape

I am able to display a image from a .eps file correctly using the below code.

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=.6\textwidth, trim={0 7cm 0 6cm},clip]{ware.eps}
\caption{Ware}\label{figures:ware}
\end{figure}
```

Now I trying to include the pdf_tex file which I exported from Inkscape but the image is not being displayed. Both the pdf and pdf_tex files are in the same directory. I am using the below code for this. I get the error "Error: File `ware.pdf_tex' not found. [\input{ware.pdf_tex}]"

```
\begin{figure}[t!]
\centering
\input{ware.pdf_tex}
\caption{Ware}\label{figures:ware}
\end{figure}
```

Could someone please help me with this issue. I am new to latex.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Maybe the size is unsuitable. Try to define `\def\svgwidth{.9\textwidth}' or similar.

Comment: @samcarter: Sorry, I just added the error. Its "Error: File `ware.pdf_tex' not found. [\input{ware.pdf_tex}]"

Comment: [Including pdf_tex images from inkscape](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125324/106162) suggests use of the [`import`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/import) package and `\import{foo.pdf_tex}` rather than `\input{foo.pdf_tex}`

Comment: Use of dot in file name is not good idea. The file extension `pdf_tex` is unknown (at least to me).

Comment: @DaiBowen: when i use import then I don't get any error but the image doesn't show up.

Comment: @aries as well as switching to `\import` you're adding `\usepackage{import}`?  I'm afraid I'm just repeating what is given as the fix in a very similar looking question rather than having personal expertise to offer here.

Comment: @DaiBowen: Yes i added \usepackage{import}, still facing the same problem.

Comment: As a work around, I am just saving in pdf directly from Inkscape now. Seems to be fine.

Comment: You say the `.pdf_tex` file is in the same directory as the `.pdf`. Is it in the same directory as your main `.tex` file? What is in the `.pdf_tex` file exactly? I'm not familiar with the process.

Comment: @aries Using your original `\input` is fine, I do this all the time for `.pdf_tex` files.

Comment: @DaiBowen `\input` is the syntax you get in the instructions, when you create the file in inkscape. In the simple case that all files are in the same directory, this should definitely work.

Comment: @Zarko The file extension `.pdf_tex` is used by inkscape for exporting the text layer of an image as tex code.

Comment: @aries Can you try two things 1) create a new `ware.tex` files and insert "hello world". Can you input this file instead of `\input{ware.pdf_tex}`? 2) In case this works, can you rename `ware.pdf_tex` to `ware.tex`?

Comment: @aries And perhaps try to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), this might make it easier to help you.

Comment: @samcarter: Thank you for your suggestion. It was a silly mistake with the path of the file. It is working fine now. Can you please tell me how to specify the dimension and trim parameters like it was with "\includegraphics?

Comment: @aries For the dimension, see my second comment. Trimming is another question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the file path not being specified properly. With "\includegraphics" I had the path specified as "\graphicspath{ {figures/} }" . However, for "\input" I had to explicitly specify the path.

```
\input{figures/ware.pdf_tex}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf). Your problem may be that your figure files aren't in the same directory as your main file, that you're missing the svgwidth line (so latex doesn't know at what size to display the image) or that you're mixing eps and pdf. Hope this helps.