# *.pdf not found when including inkscape graphic

Tags: graphics, svg, inkscape

I made a figure in inkscape to be included in my document. The document itself has the following structure

```
main.tex
   |
   |- /chapters
          |- chap1.tex
          |- chap2.tex
          |- /figures
                |- fig1.pdf
                |- fig1.pdf_tex
                |- fig1.svg
```

In the `main.tex` I include all the chapters separately. I also have there a `\graphicspath{{chapters/figures}}` to include the path to the figures. To export/import the figures from inkscape to LaTeX I follow [this](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) instruction. The including code looks like

```
\begin{figure}[]
\centering
\input{chapters/figures/fig1.pdf_tex}
\caption{Figure}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

When I now compile the document, I get the error message that file `fig1.pdf` is not found, even though it's in the same directory as `fig1.pdf_tex`.

Is there something I need to add to make it work?

**EDIT:** So I tried the solution proposed in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125324/including-pdf-tex-images-from-inkscape), but replacing the input statement with `\import{chapters/figures}{chapters/figures/fig1.pdf_tex}` leads to the same error.

Comment: What's the exact content of the `includegraphics` line in `fig1.pdf_tex`? This has been addressed before I think.

Comment: Is the pdf found if you use `\includegraphics{chapters/figures/fig1.pdf}` to your main.tex?

Comment: @ChrisH: it's `\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{fig1.pdf}}%` and I tried the solutions of [Including pdf_tex images from inkscape](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125324/including-pdf-tex-images-from-inkscape), but that didn't worked either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If I use `\includegraphics{chapters/figures/fig1.pdf}` instead of the `\input` statement, `pdflatex` finds the file and displays it in the document, just without the texts in the figure.

Comment: Now test the graphicspath command by trying `\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}`.

Comment: No, doesn't work. I have to enter the full path to the figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an extra slash to your `graphicspath`:

```
\graphicspath{{chapters/figures/}}
```

---

However, I would recommend using the [`svg`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/svg) package. It takes away this hassle by providing the `\includesvg` command and even recompiles the svg file when it has been altered.

In your case, you could write

```
\usepackage[svgpath=./chapters/figures/]{svg}
```

in your preamble and then create the figure using

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg{fig1}
    \caption{Figure}
    \label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Your edit made it work. So now I can get rid of the `*.pdf` and `*.pdf_tex` and just work on the svg-files in the `figures` folder, right?

Comment: @fukurai: No, not quite. LaTeX still imports the `.pdf` file using the `.pdf_tex` file. What the `svg` package does is call inkscape to renew these files if they are outdated (i.e. the `.svg` file changed). So inkscape will still have to be installed and the `.pdf_tex` and `.pdf` files will still appear in your images folder. Note that write18 has to be enabled (call LaTeX with the `-shell-excape` option) for this to work. Also, you might run into the bug discussed in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/243499/sharelatex-pdf-inclusion-required-page-does-not-exist-5).